# How to share an instance of a service with 2 Angular-Apps (Microfrontend) in separate repos?

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, angular-module-federation

I'm currently building an Intranet and I want to connect different applications (all Angular 14) to it.

One requirement is that the apps and the host should be in separated repos. Therefore I created 2 projects with nx and configured them, so that the apps are getting loaded dynamically. This part works pretty well.

Now my problem is to share user-information between them (including events). Therefore I created a package, which all apps and the host referenced. The idea is that there is only one UserService for the whole application (including remotes). But I get a new instance foreach remote.

Is there a way to work with one instance throughout the whole environment, or do I have to stick with the sessionStorage?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on `provideIn: platform` option on the service, but this depends on your structure. Otherwise you can create a mechanism of communication between your applications. (there are a plenty of them with pro and cons, for example `event mechanism`).